# Why can't I change position with a CSS animation

Tags: css, css-position, css-animations

I had an idea to create an animation where all the words of a tagline would start squashed on top of each other at the right and then slide left into position.

I wrapped each word in the tagline in a span tag and gave it a class of "slide". I then styled slide like this:

```
.slide {
right: 0; 
animation: slide 5s; 
-webkit-animation: slide 5s;
}
```

And then made the animation like so:

```
@keyframes slide {
0% {position: absolute;}
100% {position: static;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
0% {position: absolute;}
100% {position: static;}
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. With position: absolute they should squash right (I have position relative on the containing div, and they do squash right when I style it that way, no animation). Then returning to position: static should make them sit normally. For some reason, there's no animation taking place. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't animate position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using transitions rather than animations - triggered by javascript.

This version is likely a bit brittle though as it's relying on some trial and error to get the words to line up initially.  Buyer beware :)

**CSS** - This sets up the container offscreen with initial positions for the words in the tagline (Also not cross-browser)

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition: left 1.5s ease;
}

.container > span {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

/* Has enough specificity to override the nth-child selectors */
div.container.show > span {
    left: 0;
}

.container > span:nth-child(2) { left: -2em; }
.container > span:nth-child(3) { left: -3em; }
.container > span:nth-child(4) { left: -4em; }

.show {
    left: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tagline" class="container">
    <span>This</span>
    <span> is</span>
    <span> a</span>
    <span> tagline</span>
</div>
```

**Javascript (run unload & [not cross-browser](http://caniuse.com/classlist))**

```
var tagline = document.getElementById('tagline');
tagline.classList.add('show');
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUnA5/3/)

For a list of animatable properties see: [Animatable properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)

Comment: Pretty cool, thank you. I suppose I need to find some documentation that describes what can and can't be animated.

Comment: @KyleShevlin Added link to the css3 spec

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the effect your going for http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/q8GPq/

```
@keyframes slide {
   0% {letter-spacing: -1em;}
   100% {letter-spacing: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Not quite, but a neat effect as well. dc5's effect below is what I was going for.